# Publish Settings

Tags: verbs, noun-phrases

In a software I am building, there is a section of the user interface for setting preferences regarding how the content will be published. I see a lot of software applications using the phrase "Publish Settings", but it sounds wrong to me as "publish" is a verb. "Publishing Settings" feels awkward.

Would you have any suggestions for this or should I just go with "Publish Settings" as the section title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might in fact suggest "Publication Settings" as that can be construed as both a verb and as a noun, and *both* are correctly descriptive of what you are offering the user parameters to control.

Comment: Although "publication" brings (scientific) journals to mind much more than the act of publishing something, I will go ahead with your suggestion. Thank you!